# AddView To Fragment not showing in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, android-xml

I have a fragment in which I'm trying to add a class "CategoryOption" which extends `LinearLayout`. But, when I do AddView in my `onCreateView()`, it shows nothing.

Here is my Code for the Fragment:

```
public class ContentFragment extends Fragment {

LinearLayout navBarLayout;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_fragment, container, false);

    navBarLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.navbar_layout);
    navBarLayout.addView(new CategoryOption(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_action_rss, "RSS Feed"));

    return view;    
}
}
```

Here is my content_fragment xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/navbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is My CategoryOption Class:

```
public class CategoryOption extends LinearLayout {

int iconId;
String optionName;
LinearLayout optionLayout;
TextView tvOption;
ImageView ivIcon;

public CategoryOption(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CategoryOption(Context context, int iconId, String optionName) {
    super(context);

    this.iconId = iconId;
    this.optionName = optionName;

    optionLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    tvOption = new TextView(context);
    ivIcon = new ImageView(context);

    setupLayout();
    setupTextView();
    setupImageView();

    optionLayout.addView(ivIcon);
    optionLayout.addView(tvOption);
}

private void setupImageView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(36, 36);
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 4);
    ivIcon.setLayoutParams(params);
    ivIcon.setImageResource(iconId);
}

private void setupLayout() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    optionLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    optionLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    optionLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    optionLayout.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
    optionLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DEDEDE"));
}

private void setupTextView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    tvOption.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tvOption.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#111111"));
    tvOption.setText(optionName);
}

public int getIconId() {
    return iconId;
}

public String getOptionName() {
    return optionName;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the XML for `R.layout.content_fragment`

Comment: post your `CategoryOption` code

Comment: Did it. See the edit above

Comment: where is the onDraw method where you draw your cusotm components

Comment: I'm simply adding a layout to another layout.

Comment: @AmulyaKhare just so that you don't get confused, the button, textview and radio button is just random stuff I put to check whether the fragment was showing or not. The fragment shows properly. What doesn't show is the Category Option view in the `navbar_layout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `CategoryOption` View is extending LinearLayout, try removing your `optionLayout` field and change your code to something more like this:

```
public CategoryOption(Context context, int iconId, String optionName) {
    super(context);

    this.iconId = iconId;
    this.optionName = optionName;

    tvOption = new TextView(context);
    ivIcon = new ImageView(context);

    setupLayout();
    setupTextView();
    setupImageView();

    addView(ivIcon);
    addView(tvOption);
}

private void setupLayout() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DEDEDE"));
}
```

It seems like what you were doing is creating a reference to another LinearLayout (which does not seem necessary) to display the TextView and ImageView, when you should just add those views to the CategoryOption View itself.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you. I forgot that I can add those views to the class itself..

Comment: @ADeveloper you can also remove the get methods coz you have iconId and optionname initialized in the constructor itself

Comment: yes but i may need to change the properties of those views on user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
public class CategoryOption extends LinearLayout {

int iconId;
String optionName;
LinearLayout optionLayout;
TextView tvOption;
ImageView ivIcon;

public CategoryOption(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CategoryOption(Context context, int iconId, String optionName) {
    super(context);

    this.iconId = iconId;
    this.optionName = optionName;

    tvOption = new TextView(context);
    ivIcon = new ImageView(context);

    setupLayout();
    setupTextView();
    setupImageView();

   addView(ivIcon);
   addView(tvOption);
}

private void setupImageView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(36, 36);
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 4);
    ivIcon.setLayoutParams(params);
    ivIcon.setImageResource(iconId);
}

private void setupLayout() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    this.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    this.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
    this.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DEDEDE"));
}

private void setupTextView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    tvOption.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tvOption.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#111111"));
    tvOption.setText(optionName);
}
```

or remove the extends LinearLayout and have method called getLayout and return optionLayout

```
public class CategoryOption  {

int iconId;
String optionName;
LinearLayout optionLayout;
TextView tvOption;
ImageView ivIcon;
Context context;
public CategoryOption(Context context) {
 this.context =context;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CategoryOption(Context context, int iconId, String optionName) {
    this.context=context;
    this.iconId = iconId;
    this.optionName = optionName;

    optionLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    tvOption = new TextView(context);
    ivIcon = new ImageView(context);

}

public LinearLayout getLayout()
{
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(36, 36);
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 4);
    ivIcon.setLayoutParams(params);
    ivIcon.setImageResource(iconId);
    optionLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    optionLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    optionLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    optionLayout.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
    optionLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DEDEDE"));
    tvOption.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tvOption.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#111111"));
    tvOption.setText(optionName);
    optionLayout.addView(ivIcon);
    optionLayout.addView(tvOption);
    return optionLayout;

}
}
```